# IntelliJ JSDoc block + ESLint valid-jsdoc

Tags: webstorm, eslint, intellij-14

Here is a simple function with an auto-generated docblock from WebStorm:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @returns {string}
 */
function foo(a, b) {
    return "ad";
}
```

This is considered "invalid" by ESLint [valid-jsdoc](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-jsdoc) because the `@param` don't have the type, i.e. that should have been:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {some-type} a
 * @param {some-type} b
 * @returns {string}
 */
function foo(a, b) {
    return "ad";
}
```

I cannot figure out how to fix this. Help is appreciated

Comment: If IDE cannot figure out what parameter type it is it does not insert anything in the place for `[type]` (`{some-type}` in your case). Same as it does not generates function description or put any placeholder for parameter description -- it just creates you the basic skeleton with much info it can detect and leaves the rest for the user to fill in.

Comment: @LazyOne that's fair. But at least it could put a placeholder for it, such as `@param {type} a` instead of leaving it all out.

Comment: Well ... you can file a Feature Request ticket to WebStorm's Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Adding a placeholder with the invalid type means that this invalid type will then be used for type checking that the IDE performs, in case you forgot to update it. Adding no type won't result in false-positive errors.